# Auto run script on page load with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

How do I auto load script when a page loads?

I have this extension source:

```
{ "browser_action" : { "default_icon" : "icon.png"},
  "description" : "Alert on Google Load",
  "icons" : { "128" : "icon.png" },
  "name" : "Auto alert",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google*"],
      "js": ["myscript.js"],
      "run_at": ["document_end"]
    }
  ],
}
```

Now myscript.js includes:

```
alert("hi")
```

But when i load google.com, nothing happens.

thanks alot.

Comment: Could it be that you use 'https' instead of 'http'?

Answer (score 1):

The match pattern you are using (`http://www.google*`) is invalid. You can use the wildcard character (`*`) as *scheme*, *host* or *path* parts of URL. You can not use it as a part of *domain*.

If you want to match all Google sites, you should use this pattern:

```
*://*.google.com/*
```

You can read about match patterns, including good and bad examples, in the documentation at: http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns.html